# JRValidationException: Report design not valid

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a MySQL database named **test-3** and only one table named **student**. The table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
`student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`student_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`department` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`fathers_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`mothers_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
 )
```

So now, I want to create a report in iReport 5.5.0, I right-clicked on my report name, selected the option *Add Dataset*,  then created a new datasource and named it as **data**. I selected MySQL from the dropdown list, selected the database, made the MySQL connection and it went successful. So far, so good. Now, I have designed my report structure previously, and I have also dragged the table into my report using the drag-and-drop option in iReport (selecting field from the dataset and then drag-and-drop into the report). But whenever I click the *Preview* button, I get the following message:

```
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       
 1. Field not found : student_name      
 2. Field not found : nationality      
 3. Field not found : department
```

And my report is not loaded.

The SQL Query I ran to retrieve the resultset was this:

```
  select student_name, nationality, department 
  from student
```

Can anyone please explain where the problem is? I am absolutely a newby to JasperReports and iReport.

Comment: `I am absolutely a newby to JasperReports` - The [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) is very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to declare the fields you retrieve from the database in your report. From your example, I suppose the fields are `student_name`, `nationality` and `department`, all of them should have the class set to `java.lang.String`, since they are all `varchars`.
Your field declaration should look like this:

```
<field name="department" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

You will then be able to use them like `$F{fieln_name}`.

Now, I suppose you want to see the result data in a table. 
In this case, you will have declare the fields in the `TableDataset` and then just put a TextField in a cell and set its TextField expression to something like $F{department}.

Also, for this case, make sure to put the query in the TableDataset, not in the main dataset of the report.